# Prove that the function $\Phi :\mathcal{F}(X,Y)\longrightarrow Y$, is not injective.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

### *Given*

> > Let $\mathcal{F}(X,Y)$ be the set of *all* functions $f:X\longrightarrow Y$, and let $x_0 \in X$. Given:
> >     $$\Phi :\,\mathcal{F}(X,Y)\longrightarrow Y$$
> >     Defined by $\Phi (f)=f(x_0)$ for $f\in\mathcal{F}(X,Y)$.

### *Definition*

> > 1. The function f is **injective** if $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$ *for
> >        all* $x,y\in Dom(f)$
> > 2. The function f is **surjective** if *for every* $b\in Codom(f)$
> >        there *exists* some $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$
> > 3. The function f is **bijective** if it is both *injective and
> >        surjective*

---

### *Exercise*

Is $\Phi$ surjective, injective, bijective?

### *My Solution*

1. $\Phi$ is *surjective*

   ***Proof***:  let $y\in Y$. We will show that there exists some
   element $x\in X$ such that $\Phi(f)=f(x)=b$. Define $f(x)=y, \forall
       x\in X$, We know $f\in\mathcal{F}(X,Y)$, because $\mathcal{F}(X,Y)$
   is the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$ therefore
   $\Phi(f)=f(x_0)=y$, thus $\Phi$ is Surjective
   $\hspace{15cm}$ ${\Large ▫}$
2. $\Phi$ is *not injective:*

   ***Proof***:  Special case If $|X|=1$, then
   $\Phi$ is injective.

   But when $|X|>1$, $\Phi$ is not injective. Ok here I get stuck. I
   cant figure out how to define two functions such that $\Phi$ isn't
   injective.

---

### *My Question*

> 1. Is the *surjective proof* correct?
> 2. How can I define ***two*** functions in $\mathcal{F}$ such that
>      $\Phi$ is not injective?

***Can someone give me some hints/tips?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your surjectivity proof is ok.

You observe that $\Phi$ is injective if $|X|=1$. Note that $\Phi$ is also injective if $Y=\emptyset$ or $|Y|=1$. (You should *prove* injectivity in these three cases)

If $x_1\in X$  and $y_0, y_1\in Y$ with $x_1\ne x_0$, $y_0\ne y_1$, you can define two functions
$f,g\colon X\longrightarrow Y$, namely $f(x)=y_0$ and
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}y_0&\text{if }x=x_0,\\y_1&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
Then $\Phi(f)=\Phi(g)=y_0$, but $f\ne g$ because $f(x_1)=y_0\ne y_1=g(x_1)$.

Comment: Great, I get it now! Thank you